# Flutter MainAxisAlignment not working correctly

Tags: flutter, listview, widget

I m trying to work with MainAxixsAlignment(spaceBetween) inside a Row.
this is my code

```
ListView.separated(
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  separatorBuilder: (context, index) => Divider(
                    color: Colors.black,
                    indent: 20,
                    endIndent: 20,
                  ),
                  itemCount: prayerTimes.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) => Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: Center(
                        child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      children: [
                        Text(
                          prayerTimes[index].name,
                          style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.teal,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              fontSize: 18.0),
                        ),
                        Text(
                          prayerTimes[index].time,
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.teal, fontSize: 18.0),
                        ),
                        Icon(
                          Icons.volume_up,
                          color: Colors.teal,
                        )
                      ],
                    )),
                  ),
                )
```

result:
[image]

as you can see, when the first row title name is bigger the time in the middel row is not aligned.
How can I make the middle text widget the same alignment as the first and the last widget?

Comment: It's working as expected actually, What you need is to wrap all 3 elements from the row in ```Expanded``` so they take equal amount of space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap the first Text in Expanded and use MainAxisSize.max(remove the alignment). After that you can use padding for the time Text to set some spacing and you are done.

Comment: Thanks! should I make use of flex(inside Expanded) to make my icon to the right?

Comment: Can you provide the updated code and a screenshot?